# where are these icons locade

Tags: icon

[image: just find some]
''"
**i  see some of the icons at website(old) tutorial some image

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.